# Чтение контактов из записной книжки

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь создать функцию чтения всех контактов из записной книжки

```
public String readContacts() {
    Map<String, String> contactsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
     while(cursor.moveToNext()){
      String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
      String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

      if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0){
       Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

       while(phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
        int phoneType = phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        switch(phoneType){
         case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
          contactsMap.put(phoneNumber, name + " (Мобильный)");
          break;
         case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
          contactsMap.put(phoneNumber, name + " (Домашний)");
          break;
         case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
          contactsMap.put(phoneNumber, name + " (Рабочий)");
          break;
         case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
          contactsMap.put(phoneNumber, name + " (Другой)");
          break;
         default:
          break;
        }
       }
       phoneCursor.close();
      }
     }
    }

    cursor.close();

    JSONObject jsonob = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsonob = new JSONObject(contactsMap); 

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        String base64j = Base64.encodeToString(jsonob.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return(base64j);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return("error");
    }

}
```

В строке `jsonob = new JSONObject(contactsMap);` получаю исключение:

> null pointer
>   at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:134)

Comment: полный stacktrace в студию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать без двойной инициализации:

```
JSONObject jsonob = new JSONObject(contactsMap);
```

либо так :

```
JSONObject jsonob = null;

 try {
    jsonob = new JSONObject(contactsMap); 
 }
```